# 2010 Access Query with nested JOIN, WHERE and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by, ms-access-2010

I appreciate everyone's help and patience as I continue learning through converting a large Excel/vba system to Access.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT AccountWeeklyBalances.AccountNumber,
AccountWeeklyBalances.AccountBalance,
AccountWeeklyBalances.AccountDate,
AccountMaster.AccountName,
AccountCurrentModel.Model,
ModelDetailAllHistory.Risk
FROM ((AccountWeeklyBalances 
INNER JOIN AccountMaster 
    ON AccountMaster.[AccountNumber] = AccountWeeklyBalances.AccountNumber)

  INNER JOIN AccountCurrentModel
       ON AccountWeeklyBalances.AccountNumber=AccountCurrentModel.AccountNumber)

     INNER JOIN ModelDetailAllHistory
       ON AccountCurrentModel.Model=ModelDetailAllHistory.ModelName

             WHERE AccountWeeklyBalances.AccountDate=[MatchDate]

;
```

This works, except I want to GROUP BY the Model.  I tried adding

```
GROUP BY AccountCurrentModel.Model
```

and

```
GROUP BY ModelDetailAllHistory.ModelName
```

after the WHERE clause, but both give me an error:

```
Tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression
   'AccountNumber' as part of an aggregate function.
```

I've read several other posts here, but cannot figure out what I've done wrong.

Comment: Error message seems pretty clear. You are not aggregating hence you can't group by. You can apply Order By though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to do.  If you just want to sum the AccountBalance by ModelName, then all the other columns would have to be removed from the select statement.  If you want the sum of each model for each account, then you would just add the AccountNumber to the GROUP BY, probably before the ModelName.

When aggregating, you can't include anything in the select list that's not either an aggregate function (min, max, sum, etc) or something you are grouping by, because there's no way to represent that in the query results.  How could you show the sum of AccountBalance by ModelName, but also include the AccountNumber?  The only way to do that would be to group by both AccountNumber and ModelName.

----EDIT----

After discussing in the comments I have a clearer idea of what's going on.  There is no aggregation, but there are multiple records in ModelDetailAllHistory for each Model.  However, the only value we need from that table is Risk, and that will always be the same per model.  So we need to eliminate the duplicate Risk values.  This can be done by joining into a subquery instead of joining directly into ModelDetailAllHistory

```
 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ModelName, Risk FROM ModelDetailAllHistory) mh
   ON AccountCurrentModel.Model=mh.ModelName
```

or

```
 INNER JOIN (SELECT ModelName, max(Risk) FROM ModelDetailAllHistory GROUP BY ModelName) mh
   ON AccountCurrentModel.Model=mh.ModelName
```

Both methods collapse the multiple Risk values into a single value per Model, eliminating the duplicate records.  I tend to prefer the first option because if for some reason there were multiple Risk values for a single Model, you'd end up with duplicate records and you'd know there was something wrong.  Using max() is basically choosing an arbitrary record from ModelDetailAllHistory that matches the given Model and getting the Risk value from it, since you know all the Risk values for that model should be the same.  What I don't like about this method is it will hide data inconsistencies from you (e.g. if for some reason there are some ModelDetailAllHistory records for the same Model that don't have the same Risk value), and while it's nice to know you'll never ever get duplicate records, the underlying problem could end up rearing its ugly head in other unexpected ways.

Comment: Thank you, @KKloke.  All I'm trying to do is list the information, no summing or anything.  Right now the only place to get the Risk is from ModelDetailAllHistory, which can have multiply records for each Model - hence the attempt to group.  I considered a SELECT DISTINCT but I couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: So that means there can be multiple Risk values per model, right?  Or will the Risk value for each record in ModelDetailAllHistory be the same for a given model, even though there are multiple records that relate to that model?

Comment: The Risk values are the same for each record.  (Yes, I know - bad design. I don't need a ModelMaster, except for Risk value in this one report.  Maybe I'll change it later.)

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem better now.  There are a couple of ways you can do this.  I'm going to add to my original answer so its easier to find.

Comment: Check after the ----EDIT---- in my original answer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, KKloke.  I will try to implement this on Monday.